# Custom MapKit Annotation Lagging

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am display a simple `MKMapView` to display a collection of discovered places near the users location. Upon getting results, I am adding custom annotation views, let's say of class `MyAnnotationView` to the map.

These custom view's are displayed nicely, and I have ironed out **all** of the intricate handlers for a very nice UI. Like most would assume (or hope..), upon touching one of my markers, a separate (and custom) `MKAnnotationView` pops up to display more detail. This custom view has much more detail regarding the location found, with several buttons the user is able to interact with. The interaction is not the issue here (thankfully having overcome that obstacle).

**My issue** is, for whatever reason, there seems to be a bit of "lag" between the `TouchDown` and the `TouchUpInside` event calling, about roughly ~0.5 seconds delay to be more precise.

I have checked firing my anticipated method for **only** the `TouchDown` event, and it fires almost immediately (with the micro-delay any UIButton naturally creates).

My guess is that the `MKMapView` is the culprit. Given it is intercepting / monitoring many different `UIGestureRecognizer`'s, I'm assuming the framework is just a bit "behind" in delivering my `TouchUpInside` event..

Unfortunately, assumptions don't really help anyone, especially if they don't come with a solution. So if anyone has any idea's / workarounds as to why the event handling is experiencing this delay I would love to hear. Thanks!

### CODE REFERENCES

Here is some of my code to help:

**Custom annotation view (w/ buttons) .h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyAnnotationView.h"
@import MapKit;

@interface MyAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
```

**.m**

```
#import "MyAnnotationView.h"

@implementation MyAnnotationView {
    CGFloat width, height;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        
        width = frame.size.width, height = frame.size.height;
        
        self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
        [self addSubview:self.contentView];
        
    }
    
    return self;
    
}
```

**Adding the views**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    // Here I simply create an annotation, assign it to a new `MyAnnotationView`
    // and add the view.
    MyAnnotationView *view = [[MyAnnotationView alloc] init];
    ...

    // Note: the detailButton is just a UIButton

    // This lags...
    [view.detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchCell) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // No lag... hmm
    // [view.detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchCell) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


}
```

Comment: The delay between the `UIControlEventTouchDown ` and the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is exactly as long as the user has the finger on the button.

Comment: Lol right.. as it should be and as it is everywhere else I have ever used UIControl. Unfortunately I have logged the data to the console along with a visual aid and it fires ~1/2 a second after touching down, well after my finger has left the screen.. In fact the same view added anywhere but an MKMapView performa as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the delay is that the map view is waiting to see if you're going to double-tap to zoom in. Even if you double-tap an annotation, the map will still zoom in. You can remove the delay if you're not bothered about double-tap-to-zoom by removing the double-tap gesture from the view hierarchy.

```
- (void)removeDoubleTapGestures:(UIView *)view {
    NSArray *gestureRecognizers = [view gestureRecognizers];

    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in gestureRecognizers) {
        if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] &&
            [(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer numberOfTapsRequired] == 2) {
                [view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        }
    }

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [self removeDoubleTapGestures:subview];
    }
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad` call:

```
[self removeDoubleTapGestures:myMapView];
```

Remember though that you're modifying `MKMapView`'s view hierarchy, so if Apple change things in the future it could stop working.

Comment: Yep - wasn't going to post the solution but this is in fact why. Shortly after actually I dove into the subviews (all gestures are assigned to a nested subview, not the actual map view which was slightly confusing). I just ended up delivering the events through adding a UITapGes to my view when shown, then of course removing when deselecting. Thanks for the response tho!